# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\Users\ETREUM\Documents\Xampp\htdocs\2_tarea\body_mod.php on line 9

Tags: php, mysqli, sql

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\Users\ETREUM\Documents\Xampp\htdocs\2_tarea\body_mod.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\Users\ETREUM\Documents\Xampp\htdocs\2_tarea\body_mod.php on line 9
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\Users\ETREUM\Documents\Xampp\htdocs\2_tarea\body_mod.php on line 9

```html
<?php 
    include 'conexion.php';

    $consulta = ConsProdBod($_GET['id']);

    function ConsProdBod($id_producto)
    {
        $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM contactos WHERE id='".$id_producto."' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sentencia) or die (mysqli_error());
        $filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return [            
            $filas['id'],
            $filas['nombre'],
            $filas['edad'],
            $filas['mensaje'],
        ];
    }
 ?>
<div>
<span><h1>Modificar Contacto</h1></span>
<br>
<form action="">

<label for="">Id</label>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $consulta[0]?>"><br>
<label for="">Nombre</label>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $consulta[1]?></textarea><br>
<label for="">edad</label>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $consulta[2]?></textarea><br>
<label for="">Mensaje</label>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $consulta[3]?></textarea><br>
<br>
<button></button>
</form>
<br>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿ Donde defines la variable `$con` a la que hace referencia el error ?

Comment: Por favor leer [ask]. Debes dar contexto a tus preguntas. El código por sí solo no es suficiente. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun lo que se ve no se esta proporcionando la conexion (`$con`) a la funcion `ConsProdBod` (supongo que fue creada en `conexion.php`), pero la variable $con ***no es accesible*** desde dentro de la funcion (fuera de contexto). Puedes ajustar la funcion para que envie este como un parametro mas:

```
$consulta = ConsProdBod($con, $_GET['id']);
function ConsProdBod($con, $id_producto)
{
    $sentencia = "SELECT * FROM contactos WHERE id='".$id_producto."' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sentencia) or die (mysqli_error());
    $filas=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return [            
        $filas['id'],
        $filas['nombre'],
        $filas['edad'],
        $filas['mensaje'],
    ];
}
```

Revisa el apartado del manual de PHP sobre [Ambito de variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php) para que entiendas como funcionan las variables en distintos contextos.